# If $\,\gcd (a,0)=1,\,$ what can $a$ possibly be?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I feel like a could be any number, but $0$ is divisible by any number,so they won't be mutually exclusive. I'm not sure, maybe this is not related, but it just confused me.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by the "number" $a$. Presumably $a$ ranges over the integers or the non-negative integers. If integers, then $a$ could be $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: Hint: $\ 1 = \gcd(a,0)\,$ means $\,d\mid 1\iff d\mid a,0\iff d\mid a,\,$ true iff $\,a\mid 1\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Correction: Every integer (every number in fact) divides zero. $$a\mid 0\, \text{ for all }\,a \in \mathbb R$$

$$\gcd(a, 0) = a\,\text{ for all }\, a \in \mathbb Z$$ So, if $\,\gcd(a, 0) = 1,\,$ what must $a$ be?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this was revived.  But it is confusing.  My advice to anyone confused is to take a deep breath and go back to definitions.

Some confusing concepts that make sense if you think about them but which might at first seem counter intuitive:

1) Every number is a divisor of $0$.

Pf: Let $n$ be any number.  $n*0 = 0$.  So there exists and integer $k$ (namely $k = 0$) so that $n*k = 0$.  That is the definition being a divisor.

2) If $n>0$   then the largest divisor of $n$ is $n$ itself.

Pf:  If $m > n > 0$ then $m*k > n*k \ge n$ if $k \ge 1$.  $m*k \le 0$ if $k \le 0$.  So there is not integer $k$ so that $m*k = n$.  So nothing larger than $n$ can be a divisor of $n$.  And as $n = n*1$, $n$ is a divisor of $n$.  So $n$ is the largest divisor of $n$.

3) $m$ is a divisor of $n$ if and only if $-m$ is a divisor of $n$ if and only if $m$ is a divisor of $-n$ if and ony if $-m$ is a divisor of $-n$.

Pf: $m*k =n$ if and only if $(-m)*(-k) = n$.... etc.

This means if $n \ne 0$ then $|n| \ge n$ and $|n|$ is the largest divisor of $n$.

4) $\gcd(0,0)$ is undefined but if $n \ne 0$ then $\gcd(0,n) = |n|$.

Pf: All numbers divide $0$ so the greatest number that divides $0$ is undefined.  So $\gcd(0,0)$.

All number divide $0$ so the common divisors of $0$ and $n$ are simply the divisors of $n$.  And the largest divisor of $n$ is $|n|$.

......

So....

So if $\gcd(a,0) =1$ then $\gcd(a,0) = |a| = 1$ and $a = \pm 1$.

Oh... some more concepts:

A)Every number is a divisor of $0$ but zero is not a divisor of any number except $0$.

B) If $a \ne 0$ then $\gcd(1,a) = 1$ and $\gcd(a,a) = |a|$.

Comment: i.e. $\,\{a,0\}\,$ and $\,\{\color{#c00}a\}\,$ have the same set of *common* divisors so they have the same *greatest* common divisor $=$ greatest divisor of $\color{#c00}a$, namely. $|a|.\,$ Same proof works if we replace $\{a,0\}\,$ by $\{a,na\}\,\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

If $|a|>1$ then $|a|$ is a common divisor of $a$ and of $0$,   so  $\gcd (a,0)\geq |a|>1.$

If $a=0$ then every $n\in \mathbb N$ is a divisor of $a$ and of $0$, so $\gcd (a,0)$ does not exist.

If $a=\pm 1$ then the greatest divisor of $a$ is $1,$ and $1$ also divides $0$, so $\gcd(\pm 1,0)=1. $